# Can't input password in IBM Cloud shell

Tags: ibm-cloud

Whenever I use the ibmcloud login command, I am only able to input my email but I won't be able to input my password. Any solution please?

[image: Unable to input password]

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, when you start the IBM Cloud Shell, you are already in a session. That session is linked to your session in the [IBM Cloud console](https://cloud.ibm.com) to which you should have logged in before.

In the cloud shell, try these commands:

```
ibmcloud target

ibmcloud account show
```

If everything is ok and as planned, you should see your account.

Answer (score 0):

From the IBM Cloud CLI
You can use two different methods to log in with the CLI. For the first method, use the following steps:

Specify the --sso option with the ibmcloud login command.
Follow the URL in the prompt to get the one-time passcode.
Copy and paste the passcode value in the CLI as your input.
Try this
ibmcloud login --sso
https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/account?topic=account-federated_id&interface=cli